# SQL Server Search for multiple instances of same text in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that contains an nvarchar(max) column (MyText) containing sentences.  I need to identify all instances of a particular phrase in all rows of the (MyText) column.  Once identified I want to replace all instances with different text.

Thanks,
Brad

```
select cust_div, cust_seral 
from [dbo].[lveIntake_closing_scripts] 
where close_script like '%LMLSUnit%LMLSUnit.com%'
```

Comment: REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You are expected to try your own query, then if having difficulty, ask for help. Please add the query you have tried into the question.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there an easy way to query and identify all of the instances prior to replacing them?

Comment: LIKE **'%please use freely available TSQL documentation%'** see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is the query I used to identify rows where there are 2 instances

select cust_div, cust_seral from [dbo].[lveIntake_closing_scripts] where close_script like '%LMLSUnit%LMLSUnit.com%'

Comment: please do not use comments for code or data, edit the question instead (i just did that)

Comment: what is the problem with the query? does it not locate all the rows you need?

Comment: The query works fine, but I wanted to see how many instances of the source string is contained within each row.

Answer (score 2):

To count how many instances of the source string is contained within each row, you need to replace each instance with a string that is one character shorter, then subtract that length of the resultant string from the length of the original string. Like this:

```
select
     cust_div
   , cust_seral 
   , len(close_script) - len(replace(close_script, 'LMLSUnit.com','LMLSUnit.co'))
from [dbo].[lveIntake_closing_scripts] 
where close_script like '%LMLSUnit%LMLSUnit.com%'
```